# Как получить элементы страницы по имени тэга

Tags: java

Есть примерно такой файл xml (полный файл https://ru.files.fm/u/2uz4g74p)

```
<catESAD_cu:GoodsDescription>КОЛПАЧОК</catESAD_cu:GoodsDescription>
        <catESAD_cu:GrossWeightQuantity>3649.192</catESAD_cu:GrossWeightQuantity>
        <catESAD_cu:NetWeightQuantity>2472.192</catESAD_cu:NetWeightQuantity>
        <catESAD_cu:NetWeightQuantity2>2472.192</catESAD_cu:NetWeightQuantity2>
        <catESAD_cu:InvoicedCost>16316.47</catESAD_cu:InvoicedCost>
        <catESAD_cu:CustomsCost>41048.05</catESAD_cu:CustomsCost>
        <catESAD_cu:StatisticalCost>20107.81</catESAD_cu:StatisticalCost>
        <catESAD_cu:GoodsTNVEDCode>7612100000</catESAD_cu:GoodsTNVEDCode>
```

По нажатию на кнопку выбирается этот файл и загружаются в текстовое поле все элементы страницы xml. А как сделать, чтобы загружались в разные текстовые поля разные элементы страницы xml по имени тега?

```
private void button_downloadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    try {
     txt_result.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );


    } catch (IOException ex) {
      txt_result.setText("проблема с доступом к файлу"+file.getAbsolutePath()+ex);

    }
} else {
    txt_result.setText("Доступ к файлу отменен");
}

}
```

Comment: Построить ДОМ затем можно выбирать из него элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант можно использовать [XMLStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) (ахтунг! код не универсален, а упрощен под структуру вашего файла):

```
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    String status = "";
    try {
        // enable to switch namespaces support off, i.e. if namespace is not declared in xml 
        // factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);

        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(file));

        while(xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            int eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
            if(eventType == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                String name = xmlStreamReader.getLocalName();
                switch(name) {
                    case "GoodsDescription":
                        txt_GoodsDescription.setText(xmlStreamReader.getElementText());
                        break;
                    case "GrossWeightQuantity":
                        txt_GrossWeightQuantity.setText(xmlStreamReader.getElementText());
                        break;
                    // TODO complete for all fields
                    case "root": // replace by your document root if needed
                        break;
                    default:
                        status += "Unknown element " + name + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException | XMLStreamException ex) {
        status += "Error: " + ex;
    }
    txt_result.setText(status);
```

---

исправил:

- перенес чтение текста в известные элементы, на случай если помимо приведенного фрагмента в файле есть другие элементы.

Comment: ошибку выдает " Error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,24] Message: elementGetText() function expects text only elment but START_ELEMENT was encountered"

Comment: а можно полный xml посмотреть?

Comment: добавила ссылку

Comment: исправленный код работает на полном хмл, но структура оказалась сложнее чем в начальном сниппете, например элементы GoodsDescription повторяются. Тем не менее в принципе этот вариант будет работать.